# Failed tensorflow installation in conda virtual environment - windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, conda

I've created a new virtual environment (called tensorflow_cpu) and I've just installed tensorflow.

```
C:\Users\plain>conda create -n tensorflow_cpu pip python=3.6
C:\Users\plain>conda activate tensorflow_cpu
(tensorflow_cpu) C:\Users\plain>pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

And when I look for tensorflow, it looks like it's there:

```
(tensorflow_cpu) C:\Users\plain>pip list --local
Package              Version
-------------------- -------------------
absl-py              0.9.0
astor                0.8.1
cachetools           4.0.0
certifi              2019.11.28
chardet              3.0.4
gast                 0.2.2
google-auth          1.11.2
google-auth-oauthlib 0.4.1
google-pasta         0.1.8
grpcio               1.27.2
h5py                 2.10.0
idna                 2.8
Keras-Applications   1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing  1.1.0
Markdown             3.2.1
numpy                1.18.1
oauthlib             3.1.0
opt-einsum           3.1.0
pip                  20.0.2
protobuf             3.11.3
pyasn1               0.4.8
pyasn1-modules       0.2.8
requests             2.22.0
requests-oauthlib    1.3.0
rsa                  4.0
scipy                1.4.1
setuptools           45.2.0.post20200210
six                  1.14.0
tensorboard          2.1.0
tensorflow           2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator 2.1.0
termcolor            1.1.0
urllib3              1.25.8
Werkzeug             1.0.0
wheel                0.34.2
wincertstore         0.2
wrapt                1.12.0
```

But when I start a new python interpreter session, and try to import it I get an error message.

```
(tensorflow_cpu) C:\Users\plain>python
Python 3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan  7 2020, 15:18:16) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-p   
ackages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-     
packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-   
packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line  
101, in <module>
from tensorflow_core import *
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py",   
line 42, in <module>
from . _api.v2 import audio
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-  
packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_audio_ops.py", line 9, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line   
50, in __getattr__
module = self._load()
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line  
44, in _load
module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in   
import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-  
packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-   
packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "C:\Users\plain\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me what's going on. My OS is windows (10).

Thanks!

Comment: From an issue in the tensorflow's github  ``I finally solve the problem by installing cuda 9.0 instead of 9.2 or 10.0 with tensorflow 1.12.0 and cudnn 7.4.1.5``. [Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794)

Comment: Hi! I'm looking to use TensorFlow CPU. I thought CUDA and CUDNN were for TensorFlow GPU only? Thanks

Comment: It seem that Tensorflow >= 2.0.0 [includes GPU support too.](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)